# Facebook graph API: ID of user profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the ID of the picture that is the current profile picture for a user?

Edit: OK, seems there is no trivial way to get the ID!

However, it appears from random testing that every user has a single album with attribute `type="profile"`, and the first image in this album is always the profile picture, so it is possible to get the ID of the profile picture that way. Can some more experienced with Facebook confirm that this is indeed always the case?

Comment: This is 2016, and I couldn't find a way to get the same. For album type="profile", it is not always the case that the first picture is always the profile picture. If we select an "very old" profile picture within this album, the first picture doesn't change. I am also looking out for a solution if someone can help!

Answer (score 17):

You can get the users public profile photo from the following url:

https://graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture

Reference:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: That doesn't give you the photo ID though

Answer (score 5):

The answer seems to be ***yes***

e.g., the photos in an album have an ID (the profile photo is a different object though, which a different FB ID). An ID for every object is a core concept of FB's new graph API: *Every object in the social graph has a* [*unique ID*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api).

Indeed, data request i have ever made through the FB Graph API returns (when successful) a response in the form of a JSON array, comprised of nested ID-Value pairs, e.g. the *education field* from a User object:

```
"education": [
    {
       "school": {
           "id": "126533127390327",
           "name": "Massachusetts Institute of Technology"
    },
       "year": {
            "id": "140829239279495",
            "name": "1992"
    },
       "concentration": [
           {
                "id": "192578844099494",
                "name": "Computer Science"
           }
       ],
       "type": "College"
}
```

The [profile photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) is a *connection* of the ***User*** object (i.e., every FB object has *Fields* and *Connections*).

According to the table in the relevant [FB Developer Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), a call to the Graph API requesting *picture* (user's profile photo(s)) ***returns a string which is the URL for the user's profile picture***.

But why doesn't this same call return the user's profile photo *ID*?

The reason i suppose is that the URL returns:

```
Graph API : User Properties
```

The user's profile photo is not there, but in an adjacent node:

```
Graph API : User : Connections : picture
```

(See FB Documentation for Graph API structure [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)).

When you make that API call, examine the ***Request Headers***, and in particular, the ***Request URL***; when you do, you'll see something like this:

```
http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/32093_100005743929541_5467982_q.jpg
```

The string between the underscores (100005743929541) is the user ID. this is easy to verify by making another call to the Graph API. From your browser location bar (assuming you are logged into Facebook) just enter:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

So again, the first item in that JSON string is the user's FB ID. Given that, it seems to me that if user profile ID does indeed have its own ID, then **that string (user's FB ID) plus the two smaller adjacent strings of integers** on either end of the ID, should be it--in other words, 32093_100005743929541_5467982 in the Request URL above.

Finally, perhaps the best way to answer this is by using the new [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). (I just tried to verify this, but my requests are hanging.)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can reliably get the user ID from the profile picture anymore. Here's my user ID from `/me`: 10153540253304706. Here's the ID extracted from my profile picture URL: 10152550339904706. They don't match.

Answer (score 2):

There is one more simple way to accomplish this task.

1. Fetch all facebook albums by https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=.
2. Loop into the albums and check if object **type** == 'profile'.
3. Get the value of object **cover_photo** where **type** == 'profile'.

This value of **cover_photo** is the id of profile pic of the user.

You can check it by https://graph.facebook.com/<**cover_photo value**>?access_tokne=

Comment: "This value of cover_photo is the id of profile pic of the user." - That is not the case

Comment: I guess this is correct answer, becuse simple testing shows that cover of this album is always equals the profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need this but this is the way I did it in PHP:

```php
$albumsfb = $facebook->api('/me/albums/?fields=type');
$albumsfb = $albumsfb['data'];
foreach ($albumsfb as $albumfb) {
    if ($albumfb['type']=='profile'){
        $albumprofile = $albumfb['id'];
        break;
    };
}
$photoprofilefb = $facebook->api('/'.$albumprofile.'/?fields=cover_photo');
$photoprofilefb = $photoprofilefb['cover_photo'];
$photoprofilefb = $facebook->api('/'.$photoprofilefb);
$fotoperfilfburl = $photoprofilefb['source'];
```

Instead of "me", put the user id that you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<SOCIAL-ID>/picture?type=<small|normal|album|large|square>
```

SOCIAL-ID = Facebook returned social id.

small|normal|album|large|square = size of image.

Answer (score -1):

I recently tried to like one of my friend's profile pictures from the Graph API explorer

Here's how I got the id of his current profile pic:

```
fields=friends..fields(albums.fields(photos.fields(id,name,link),name))
```

If you have used the Graph API explorer, you might be aware of the above line of code that's generated in the textEntry when you tick the checkboxes. The limit size is up to you, I just kept it 1 to receive the JSON object quickly (without the limit, it took me 5 minutes to get the JSON object containing a lot of information).

So here are the things you need to check in the Graph API (maintain the order):

Friends
Within Friends Albums
Within Albums Name and Photos (Within Photos the id and name of the photo)

I made a PHP script to like all the profile pictures of my friends :)