# I have a list of Facebook user ids. Is there a way I can easily download them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, profile, image

I currently have them in an excel spreadsheet. I know i can get them 1 by 1 ([Facebook graph API: ID of user profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959483/facebook-graph-api-id-of-user-profile-picture)) but is there a way to get all of them at once?

Answer (score 1):

Well in order to download the images you will need to make a request to each URL. However you will be able to get a list of all the URL's in one request. You can use an FQL statement for this:

```
SELEXT pic_big FROM user WHERE uid IN (UID1,UID2,...)
```

You'll get a response similar to this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "pic_big": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/xxx.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "pic_big": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/yyy.jpg"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Using PHP for example you could loop over the results and use a combination of `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` to download the image:

```
$imageData = json_decode($fqlResult,true);
foreach($imageData['data'] AS $key => $value){
  file_put_contents('/new/path/to/image',file_get_contents($value));
}
```